# Magento Bug Bounty - New Admin XSS Vulnerability

Tags: magento-1, security

Is the Magento 1 bug bounty still active?  I've found a new obscure XSS vector that will allow attackers to take control of administrator sessions and would like to submit the procedure, yet I don't see the form on the Magento site anymore.

If the bounty isn't running anymore, that would be a bummer...and if that's the case, then what is the preferred method of contact?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also report the bug at the Magento lts discord group (security) or log it in github lts (not the vulnerability...only the report of having found it ... you willen contacted after I assume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Magento Security Center](https://magento.com/security) the link for reporting security bugs links to https://bugcrowd.com/magento.

It seems they just moved the bug bounty programme to bugcrowd lately.